# Нужно ли пользовать signed по отношению к числам?

Tags: c++, c

Есть ли разница между:

```
int a = 8;
```

и

```
signed int a = 8;
```

и есть ли случай, когда signed обязательно?
в C и C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signed` добавляет разницу только применительно к `char`, т.е. `signed char` и `char` - это разные типы, в то время как `signed int` и `int` - одинаковые. Обычно пользоваться им не нужно, а вместо этого использовать надлежащие алиасы типов.

Answer (score 2):

В языке С ключевое слово `signed` имеет эффект в двух контекстах:

1. В применении к типу `char`.  При этом `unsigned char`, `signed char` и `char` - три разных типа и не гарантируется, что `char` имеет знаковый тип.

   ```
   signed char   a; // <- знаковый целый тип
   unsigned char b; // <- беззнаковый целый тип
   char          c; // <- знаковость определяется реализацией
   ```
2. В применении к битовому полю. Без `signed` не гарантируется, что битовое поле имеет знаковое представление, даже если в объявлении поля использовался знаковый тип. Знаковость битовых полей, объявленных без явного указания `signed` или `unsigned`, определяется реализацией

   ```
   signed int   a : 2; // <- знаковое поле
   unsigned int b : 2; // <- беззнаковое поле
   int          c : 2; // <- знаковость определяется реализацией
   ```

В языке С++ второй пункт не имеет места. Знаковость битовых полей в С++ подчиняется общим правилам, т.е. совпадает со знаковостью использованного в объявлении типа.

То есть если вы не хотите, чтобы ваш код был завязан на особенности реализации, в этих случаях необходимо указание `signed` для получения знакового типа или представления. В остальных случаях добавление `signed` в описание целочисленного типа не влияет на тип.